# AngularJS data push

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following AngularJS app.

From `$scope.forms` I create some inputs on the html part using `ng-repeat`.

The thing I dont understand is how to push the data from       `attributes: ["title", "firstname", "lastname", "address"]` inputs into       `values: []`

Can someone explain me how to push the input values into my values key?
Or maybe if there is a best solution to explain?

```
function sampleCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.forms = [
    {
      title: "Something",
      attributes: ["title", "firstname", "lastname", "address"],
      values: [] //here i want the values from the attributes
    },
    {
      title: "Something else",
      attributes: ["title", "name", "job", "address"],
      values: [] //here i want the values from the attributes
    }   ]; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/18198/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [@Grundy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32242694/419956) for a direct approach where you don't have to change your model.

Do allow me to suggest a different approach though (that also includes the fact that you need to use [`ng-model`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) to bind the `input`'s `value`): model the attribute + value combination as an actual thing. So e.g.:

```
$scope.forms = [
    {
        title: "Something",
        pairs: [{label: "title", value: ""}, {label: "firstname", value: ""}]
    }
];
```

This view model is much easier to bind to in a view:

```
<div ng-repeat="pair in form.pairs">
    <input type="text" placeholder="{{pair.label}}" ng-model="pair.value" />
</div>
```

The reason I suggest this is because the `$scope` works best IMO if it's tailored to being bound to in views. If you need the other format (i.e. a `values` array) perhaps to send it off to a back end service, you'd best map the view model back to the appropriate data format. For example:

```
var values = $scope.forms[0].pairs.map(function(p) {
    return p.value;
});
```

See [this forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9jj8guf/) for a full example.

Answer (score 2):

You should see about [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel). as model you can use `values[$index]` so, in `values` array values in same order as in `attributes`.

```js
function sampleCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.forms = [
    {
      title: "Something",
      attributes: ["title", "firstname", "lastname", "address"],
      values: [] //here i want the values from the attributes
    },
    {
      title: "Something else",
      attributes: ["title", "name", "job", "address"],
      values: [] //here i want the values from the attributes
    }
  ];

}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: courier new;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.form {
    margin: 0 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <div ng-controller="sampleCtrl">
      
        <div class="form" ng-repeat="form in forms">
          <h2>{{form.title}}</h2>     
          <div ng-repeat="input in form.attributes">
              <input type="text" ng-model="form.values[$index]" placeholder="{{input}}" />
          </div>
            {{form.attributes}}
            {{form.values}}
        </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Aye, +1, similar to my solution, only one where OP will not have to change the current `$scope`'s format with two seperate arrays.

Comment: @Jeroen, yep, in some cases we can't change structure :-) any way main problem OP - he not use `ng-model` :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have added the changes to your fiddle:

```
<div ng-app>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <div ng-controller="sampleCtrl">

        <div class="form" ng-repeat="form in forms">
          <h2>{{form.title}}</h2>     
          <div ng-repeat="input in form.attributes" ng-init="mod = []">
              <input type="text" placeholder="{{input}}" ng-init="mod[$index] = form.values[$index]" ng-model="mod[$index]"/>
          </div>
       </div>     
   </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/18201/

Comment: why you use so many ng-init? in this case when you change values in input, they not applied to `values` array

Comment: Yeah. just saw your answer it could be done using the form.values array. I thought we would need another array to store the value in, but I was naive. :3

Comment: anyway, you create new `mod` array on every nested ng-repepeat iteration :-) just see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/18208/

Comment: Oh yeah. the div gets rendered multiple times and initializes it everytime. should have done ng-init above the ng-repeat. Anyways, Thanks for it. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's simple : Here is [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/18203/)

Just added an `ng-model` that points at the exact same index in `attributes` array and that of in `values` array.

```
  <div ng-app>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <div ng-controller="sampleCtrl">

        <div class="form" ng-repeat="form in forms">
          <h2>{{form.title}}</h2>     
          <div ng-repeat="input in form.attributes">
              <input type="text" ng-model="form.values[$index]"  placeholder="{{input}}" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button ng-click="haha()">Test!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And no change in JS. Only added new function `haha()` to test it out

```
function sampleCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.forms = [
    {
      title: "Something",
      attributes: ["title", "firstname", "lastname", "address"],
      values: [] //here i want the values from the attributes
    },
    {
      title: "Something else",
      attributes: ["title", "name", "job", "address"],
      values: [] //here i want the values from the attributes
    }
  ];

    $scope.haha = function(){
        console.log($scope.forms);
    }

}
```

Comment: do you have any difference from my answer except `haha`? :-)